# How would you test this generic API?

Tags: swift

I've got the following `APIRequest` protocol:

```
protocol APIRequest {
    associatedtype Result

    var httpMethod: HTTPMethod { get }
    var pathComponents: [String] { get }
    func handle(responseData: Data) throws -> Result
}
```

Additionally, I've got the following `APIClient` protocol:

```
protocol APIClientProtocol {
    func perform<T : APIRequest>(_ request: T,
                                 completion: @escaping ((Result<T.Result, APIError>) -> Void))
}
```

Then I've got a class which takes an `APIClientProtocol` and make the request. IE:

```
final class DataSource {
  let client: APIClientProtocol

  init(client: APIClientProtocol) {
    self.client = client
  }
  

  func fetchThing(completion: @escaping (Result<Thing, APIError>) -> Void) {
    let thingRequest = ThingRequest() // This is an APIRequest
    client.perform(thingRequest, completion: { result in
      switch result {
        case .success(let thing):
          completion(.success(thing))
        case .failure(let error):
          completion(.failure(error))
      }
   }
}
```

Now I want to write a test for `DataSource` but I need to mock `APIClientProtocol` in order to do that. How can I mock it?

Comment: I agree with Sulthan's answer, but you also may find this helpful, which addresses exactly this issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXwJg0QTlZE

Answer (score 2):

Using a mock of `URLProtocol` is thinking too deep.

There are two basic ways to mock API.

1. Create a full mock server and connect to it instead of your real server. This way you can create integration tests.
2. Just mock the response directly

```
class APIClientProtocolMock: APIClientProtocol {
   func perform<T : APIRequest>(
      _ request: T,
      completion: @escaping ((Result<T.Result, APIError>) -> Void)
   ) {
      // replace with a background queue depending on your implementation
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(.success(/* put your mock response here */))
      }
   }
}
```

To be honest, I am not a big friend of unit testing on FE with extensive mocking because e2e tests (UI tests) do a much better job and you don't have to create hundreds of unnecessary protocols for mocking to work.

A real example:

```
protocol APIRequest {
    associatedtype Result

    var httpMethod: String { get }
    var pathComponents: [String] { get }
    func handle(responseData: Data) throws -> Result
}

protocol APIClientProtocol {
    func perform<T : APIRequest>(
        _ request: T,
        completion: @escaping ((Result<T.Result, Error>) -> Void)
    )
}


struct MockAPIRequest: APIRequest {
    typealias Result = String

    let httpMethod: String = "POST"
    let pathComponents: [String] = ["url"]

    func handle(responseData: Data) throws -> Result {
        return "success"
    }
}

struct SecondMockAPIRequest: APIRequest {
    typealias Result = String

    let httpMethod: String = "POST"
    let pathComponents: [String] = ["url"]

    func handle(responseData: Data) throws -> Result {
        return "failed"
    }
}

class MockAPIClientProtocol: APIClientProtocol {
    var mockData: [String: Data] = [:]

    // you can load mock data dynamically
    func perform<T : APIRequest>(_ request: T, completion: @escaping ((Result<T.Result, Error>) -> Void)) {
        let data = mockData[request.pathComponents.joined(separator: "/")] ?? Data()
        completion(.success(try! request.handle(responseData: data)))
    }

    // you can add implementation for a specific type
    func perform(_ request: SecondMockAPIRequest, completion: @escaping ((Result<SecondMockAPIRequest.Result, Error>) -> Void)) {
        let data = mockData[request.pathComponents.joined(separator: "/")] ?? Data()
        completion(.success(try! request.handle(responseData: data)))
    }
}

let client = MockAPIClientProtocol()
client.mockData["url"] = Data()
client.perform(MockAPIRequest()) { result in
    print(result) // success
}
client.perform(SecondMockAPIRequest()) { result in
    print(result) // failed
}
```

Comment: Re: 2, this is the path I'm going down, but the part within `.succes()` is whats interesting, and I can't figure out how to make it work. The result is a function of `T` which is `APIRequest`, which has an `associatedType`. How do you instantiate the mock with a proper stub value?

Comment: Well, in my opinion you are missing one level of abstraction. Your method is good for network layer requests but usually you should have an abstraction communication layer with methods like `func loadData(for object: Object, onCompletion: (Result<ResponseObject, RequestError>) -> Void)` which shouldn't be generic at all. This layer should be the one creating the requests and parsing response.

Comment: However, the mock can still be generic which would solve the problem. If you are trying to use the same mock for multiple requests, that won't work.

Comment: I've updated my question a bit. I do have another layer which isn't generic and interfaces with the generic protocol. Now I want to test that layer, but I need to inject the generic protocol, and I'm not sure how.

Comment: @PeterFoti I have added an example how to test that protocol.